# How to pivot a table into a timeseries table in Scala

Tags: scala, pivot

I have the following table:

```
index   0       1       2       id  
1       9.69    1.18    0.59    62
2       7.38    2.18    0.87    62
3       10.02   1.16    0.29    62
```

That I'm trying to pivot into a time series like table.

Expected Output:

```
data                    id
[9.69, 7.38, 10.02]     62
[1.18, 2.18, 1.16]      62
[0.59, 0.87, 0.29]      62
```

I tried the following code

```
val table = df.groupBy(df.col("id")).pivot("index").sum("0").cache()
val tablets = table.map(x => new transform(1.until(x.length).map(x.getDouble(_)).toList, x.getString(0)))
case class transform(data:List[Double], start:String)
```

But it's given only this output

```
[9.69, 7.38, 10.02]     62
```

How can I iterate through all columns and get the desired output table as above?

```
class pivot (df: DataFrame) {


val col1Names = df.drop("id").columns.tail
val kv = explode(array(df.select(col1Names.map(col): _*).columns.map {
c => struct(lit(c).alias("k"), col(c).alias("v"))
}: _*))

val tempdf = df.withColumn("kv", kv)
.select("index", "kv.k", "kv.v", "id")
.groupBy("id", "k")
.pivot("index")
.agg(first("v"))
.drop("k")

val col2Names = tempdf.columns.tail
val finaldf = tempdf.withColumn("data", array(col2Names.map(col): _*)).drop(col2Names: _*)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your solution you have used `groupBy` and `sum` which will generate `aggregated` one `row` for each group. Thats why you were getting one result in your result.

The solution to your problem is a bit complex. I have used combination of `withColumn, explode, array, struct, pivot, groupBy, agg, drop, col, select and alias`. Following is the solution

```
   val df = Seq((1, 9.69,  1.18, 0.59, 62),
     (2, 7.38,  2.18, 0.87, 62),
     (3, 10.02, 1.16, 0.29, 62)).toDF("index", "0", "1", "2", "id")
```

As defined in your question you must already have dataframe as below by reading input as above

```
+-----+-----+----+----+---+
|index|0    |1   |2   |id |
+-----+-----+----+----+---+
|1    |9.69 |1.18|0.59|62 |
|2    |7.38 |2.18|0.87|62 |
|3    |10.02|1.16|0.29|62 |
+-----+-----+----+----+---+
```

If yes then following solution should work.

```
val col1Names = df.drop("id").columns.tail
val kv = explode(array(df.select(col1Names.map(col): _*).columns.map {
  c => struct(lit(c).alias("k"), col(c).alias("v"))
}: _*))

val tempdf = df.withColumn("kv", kv)
                .select("index", "kv.k", "kv.v", "id")
                .groupBy("id", "k")
                .pivot("index")
                .agg(first("v"))
                .orderBy("k")
                .drop("k")

  val col2Names = tempdf.columns.tail
  val finaldf = tempdf.withColumn("data", array(col2Names.map(col): _*)).drop(col2Names: _*).sort($"data".desc)
```

You should be getting following output

```
+---+-------------------+
|id |data               |
+---+-------------------+
|62 |[9.69, 7.38, 10.02]|
|62 |[1.18, 2.18, 1.16] |
|62 |[0.59, 0.87, 0.29] |
+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it isn't actually working as expected. That was a lot to process so I broke it down to analyze intermediate output. Applying `.columns.tail` and `val tempdf = df.withColumn("kv", kv) `returns an empty dataframe and when I remove the .tails part, the dataframe returns `index  0 1 2 id` as a column and even splitting that won't give me the expected output.

Comment: Here's what I'm getting instead(single row):

[ 62, 1   9.69    1.18    0.59    62, 2   7.38    2.18    0.87    62, 3   10.02   1.16    0.29    62]

Comment: your code is not compiling. Why did you add `val split_col = split(df.col("index   0   1   2   id"), "   ")`? It compiled after I removed the line. And you were getting above result which was different than expected because you missed `.tail` in `val col2Names = tempdf.columns` line.

Comment: I added `val split_col = split(df.col("index 0 1 2 id"), " ")` cos when I add .tail it returns an empty dataframe and when I remove it I have to split the columns back to original. Are you able to get the expected output with the compiled code? I'm still not

Comment: I have updated my answer . Please take a look. And I doubt that you have input dataframe as in my updated answer. And one more thing : how are you calling pivot class from other class (main)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I indeed get the output you've shown above. One minor thing, why does [1.18, 2.18, 1.16]  comes before [9.69, 7.38, 10.02] ? Since it's time dependent orders matter but I guess should be an easy fix.

Comment: @EricF. I have updated my answer for sorting as well. you just need to call `.sort($"data".desc)` . I hope thats exactly what you are looking for. :)